# If two sprites are visible, do something (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite

I'm creating a memory like game. I built all the desktop, the cards generation. I now have two cards of each.

I'm trying to do the pairs delete system.

my function to show the color to find looks like this :

```
private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (vueDos)
            {
                vueDos          = !vueDos;

                faceCarte       = new Sprite();
                faceCarte.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x000000,.5);
                faceCarte.graphics.beginFill(clr);
                faceCarte.graphics.drawRoundRect(8,8,this.width - 16, this.height - 16, 10,10);
                faceCarte.graphics.endFill();

                var _t:TextField    = new TextField();
                _t.selectable       = false;
                _t.antiAliasType    = "advanced";
                _t.autoSize         = "left";
                _t.defaultTextFormat= new TextFormat(maFont.fontName,24,0x000000);
                _t.text             = couleur;
                _t.x                = (this.width - _t.width)/2
                _t.y                = (this.height - _t.height) >> 1;

                faceCarte.addChild(_t);
                faceCarte.cacheAsBitmap = true;
                this.addChild(faceCarte);
            }

            if(!vueDos) 
        }
```

Does it exist a function wich see if the color of the card is visible (faceCarte), and limit the visibles carte to two then removeChild faceCart.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you be more specific? I can't get what's wrong with your code...

Answer (score 0):

You have to make such a function yourself. It'll be better to assign a `couleur` property to the card itself, instead of putting it into the TextField and forgetting. This way you'll be able to open first card, get that property, then open second card and compare that one's property with what you received, if match, both cards will be removed.